# TFS 2012 (Cloud): Add new Collection

Tags: collections, tfs, visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

We are just trying the new Team Foundation Service and we want to migrate our data to it.
In our old (local server) installation of TFS2010 we have several collections. But we can't find a way to add collections in the Service interface.

Is there a possibility to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not currently possible in Team Foundation Service.

There is a request for this feature in UserVoice.  Go and vote on it to help it get prioritised.

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3473653-let-us-create-multiple-collections-on-team-foundat